# Set a Variable from a filename to read all the files from a directory

Tags: regex, sas, filenames

I want to set a new variable with filename in SAS. I have a bunch of txt files in a folder, I have a macro that reads all my text files, along with this I want to create another variable where it reads all the filenames.

what I am trying to do is very similar to the question asked here before

[SAS set a variable from a filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812279/sas-set-a-variable-from-a-filename)

and the solution offered here works for me, except it only reads only one of my file. How can I use this in a macro or even by its own to input all my filenames.

```
reg1=prxparse("/\\(\w+\.csv)/");
if prxmatch(reg1, filename) then filename=prxposn(reg1,1,filename);
```

what I want is to input all my text file names along with the other variables the text files has. 
Eg:

```
filename var1 var2 var3
text1    xxx  xxx  xxx
text2    yyy  yyy  yyy
```

I have also tried the second solution offered in the link. I am using SAS EG and it's not allowing me to use pipe symbol. Sorry if my question is too basic. I am new to using perl expressions.

Comment: How is this Perl related? It's using regex similar to Perl? I would suggest to tag with regex instead.

Comment: You don't need regex or a macro.

Answer (score 1):

With only one line it's hard to explain why that code didn't work for you.

Here's my solution - no regex or macro.

```
data import_all;

*make sure variables to store file name are long enough;
length filename txt_file_name $256;

*keep file name from record to record;
retain txt_file_name;

*Use wildcard in input;
infile "Path\*.txt" eov=eov filename=filename truncover;

*Input first record and hold line;
input@;

*Check if this is the first record or the first record in a new file;
*If it is, replace the filename with the new file name and move to next line;
if _n_ eq 1 or eov then do;
txt_file_name = scan(filename, -1, "\");
eov=0;
end;

*Otherwise  go to the import step and read the files;
else input

 *Place input code here;

;
run;
```