# filevar infile statement to read in multiple txt file

Tags: sas

from [this link](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146932.htm) i learnt how to read multiple txt file.

**Problem: is it possible to create a macro variable to input all txt file in a folders. say C:\Users\Desktop\ (given all files are in txt format with name datasetyyyymmdd.)**

I have dataset20150101.txt - dataset20150806.txt and i do not want to manually input all those linkage in the datalines.

```
data whole2;
    infile datalines;
    length fil2read $256;
    input fil2read $;
    infile dummy filevar=fil2read end=done dsd;
    do while (not done);
        input name$ value1 value2;
        output;
    end;
    datalines;
C:\Users\Desktop\dataset20150501.txt
C:\Users\Desktop\dataset20150502.txt
run;
```

Comment: Hi useR, I don't understand your question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: HI i have unknown number of dataset file in a subfolder. and i want to include all the dataset.

Comment: Use a wildcard in your filename. See answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844986/set-a-variable-from-a-filename-to-read-all-the-files-from-a-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask the operating system which files are present:

```
filename DataIn pipe "dir C:\Users\Desktop\dataset*.txt /S /B";   

data whole2;
    infile DataIn truncover;
    length fil2read $256;
    input fil2read $;
    infile dummy filevar=fil2read end=done dsd;
    do while (not done);
        input name$ value1 value2;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

The Bare option `/B` removes unneeded information like last access date.

I added the Sub-folder option `/S` because then the dir statement returns full path names. This way it also reads `dataset*.txt` files in subfolder of `C:\Users\Desktop\`. If that does not suite you, remove the `/S` and use

```
    path2Read = "dir C:\Users\Desktop\"||fil2read;
```

Comment: HI @Dirk, Thanks for your answer. It popup a error message ERROR: Physical file does not exist, C:\Users\dataset1.txt. As you can see i do not why it change the directory without the Desktop folder.

Comment: @useR, I did not test it, sorry. Apparently, the Bare option `/B` alone just gives you file names. If you add the Sub-folder option`/S`, as I usually do, you get full path names. You can use that while I do some more testing.

Comment: After input fil2read $; Add: files="C:\Users\Desktop\"||fil2read; replace fil2read with files in infile as: infile dummy filevar=files end=done dsd;